# Spring Data JPA: Find all by example and page and return DTO (Projection)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to find all data for my entity as EntityDTO. I know how to find all data as DTO but I want to place some filters using Example object and fetch Page as result.

I created a method in repository as:

```
Page<T> findBy(Example e, Pageable p, Class<T> type);
```

But invoking this method is resulting in error

> IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0
>   parameter(s) present in query.

Here is full stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132.findBy(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: 1) Show the full stacktrace. 2) Check if you have set any attributes to the parameter `e`.

Comment: @mentallurg 1) I have added full stacktrace. 2) I am using Example because sometimes I get some params some times I don't. Also, I tried adding a param in `e` but I get the same result. And, when I don't pass anything in `e` and use findAll with `Page<Entity>` as return, I get expected result.

Comment: If `e` is empty (null or all its attributes are null), then you cannot use search by example because there is *no example*. In such case you should use the *findAll()* method.

Comment: @mentallurg As mentioned in my previous comment, I am getting the same error even after setting values of attributes. It seems that I cannot pass Example in findBy method.

Comment: Exactly. That is what I mean. If Example is empty, you cannot search by example. Use findAll() - without parameters or with a paging parameter, but of course you cannot pass Example to findAll().

Answer (score 0):

In Spring repository interface, the query is created from the method name.

Please try this:

```
Page<T> findByExample(Example e, Pageable p, Class<T> type);
```

If it doesn't work you might find the solution here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories